# Vertical offset in bullets

Tags: itemize, moderncv

I'm using the moderncv class, and so far is pretty nice, except that I would like to move the bullets a bit higher (by default they are aligned to the bottom of the line).

Here is a small example

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvitem{}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First item.
        \item Second item.
        \item Third item.
    \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

I know bullets can be redefined with something like: `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}`

But I don't know what to add to the default definition (bellow) in order to displace them vertically:

```
\newcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\large\rmfamily\textbullet}}
```

Comment: Technically [this is not true](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yjfH9.png)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{red}{\raisebox{2pt}{\large\rmfamily\textbullet}}}
```

for example, to raise the bullet.